# Validação de string (isograma)

Tags: php

Ao criar uma função que retorna `false` caso existam letras repetidas em uma palavra e `true` caso não haja o seguinte teste passa com os caracteres:

```
$this->assertTrue(isIsogram('Heizölrückstoßabdämpfung'));
```

Mas falha no seguinte teste:

```
$this->assertFalse(isIsogram('éléphant'));
```

A função que é chamada é a seguinte:

```
function isIsogram(string $text) {
    $letters = array_filter(str_split(strtolower($text)), function($value) {
    $v = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/i', '', $value);
    return !empty($v);
});

    $uniq = array_unique($letters);
    $diff = array_diff_assoc($letters, $uniq);

    return count($diff) > 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Com letras em alemão o teste é aplicado e passa normalmente porém as letras `é` são removidas quando usado o `preg_replace`, como posso aplicar esta validação para caracteres que utilizamos em nosso idioma?

Comment: O problema é que ele remove `é` ou `ç` isso?

Comment: sim, não existe nenhum teste com `ç`, mas com `é` sim...

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é utilizar `mb_convert_case()` para converter corretamente todos os caracters acentuados corretamente. `preg_replace()` é responsavel por remover qualquer caracter que seja uma letra ou dígito.

`preg_split()` faz o mesmo que `str_split()` porém não 'masca' caracteres acentuados.

```
$text = 'aççao88';



function isIsogram($text) {
    $str = mb_convert_case(preg_replace('/\W/u', '', $text), MB_CASE_LOWER);
    $letters = preg_split('//u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $uniq = array_unique($letters);
    $diff = array_diff_assoc($letters, $uniq);

    return count($diff) > 0;
}
```